# How to add DN for liferay LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, connection, liferay, dn

I want to configure LDAP for my portal. I have added the connection details such as:

**Connection**

```
Base Provider URL : ldap://SBS.ecompany.local:300(example)
Base DN: ecompany.local
Principal : myldap username
Credentials: myldap password.
```

also did the following mappings:

```
Screen Name : sn
Email Address: mail
Password: userPassword
First Name: givenName
Middle Name
Last Name: sn
Full Name: givenName sn
Job Title : title
```

I checked for the connection, and I got the following message:

> Liferay has successfully connected to the LDAP server.

When I checked for Test LDAP Users I got the following message:

> Test LDAP Users A subset of users has been displayed for you to review.
>   No users were found.

(Might be because I did not provide LDATP admin uname and pwd)

But when I tried to login I was not able to login using the LDAP configuration.
And got this error:

```
09:38:33,808 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-5][PortalLDAPImporterImpl:210] Error importing LDAP users and groups
javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Empty filter; remaining name 'ecompany.local'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Filter.encodeFilterString(Filter.java:57)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:548)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1985)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1844)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil.searchLDAP(PortalLDAPUtil.java:820)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil.getUsers(PortalLDAPUtil.java:617)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil.getUsers(PortalLDAPUtil.java:652)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAPByUser(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:695)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:203)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:139)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterUtil.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterUtil.java:43)
at com.liferay.portlet.admin.messaging.LDAPImportMessageListener.doImportOnStartup(LDAPImportMessageListener.java:38)
at com.liferay.portlet.admin.messaging.LDAPImportMessageListener.doReceive(LDAPImportMessageListener.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor405.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy303.receive(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:77)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error is because of the DN. Can somebody help me solve this issue.

Comment: Your base DN could be possibly dc=ecompany,dc=local
That was based on "Base DN: ecompany.local" info you provided above.
Again it is depending on what you have actually configured inside your ldap server.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with an another issue. The problem was with the authentication search filter . I gave the format as :
Authentication Search Filter : `Authentication Search Filter" as (mail=@email_address@)`. Actual format is  Authentication Search Filter : `(mail=@email_address@)`
Next, the dn : format is `dc=ecompany, dc=local`.
The problem of ldap configuration was solved.

But when I  changed the search filter from mail to screen name ie  Authentication Search Filter : `(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)` and also changed the *How do users authenticate*? to *By screen name*. 
But I am not able to login using the ldap screen name and password. I checked the log files. I did not find any error. Please help .